# How to stop going to redirected URL in Google App Engine with Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, redirect, urlfetch

I'm using `urlfetch` from google app engine, but it keeps going to the redirected final page even though I use:

```
result = urlfetch.fetch(classUrl, payload=None, method=urlfetch.GET, headers={}, allow_truncated=False, follow_redirects=False)
```

E.g. if classUrl was a searched term in Google

```
(https://www.google.com/search?q=setInstanceFollowRedirects()+python&oq=setInstanceFollowRedirects()+python&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
```

it would redirect me to www.google.com

How do I stop this redirection?

Comment: It seems you should use `search api` not fetch the results page directly.

Comment: Sorry about the misdirection, but the url i'm trying to open is not google.com, but http://registrar.ucla.edu/schedule/detselect.aspx?termsel=12F&subareasel=COM+SCI&idxcrs=0033++++
The thing is, it goes to the webpage but without the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a cookie problem, some sites insist on making at least one 302 ruondtrip to set a required cookie. You'll have to manage the cookies yourself. There are other questions on SO that explain how to do this.